# Google colab and local runtime setting

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

I successfully connected my notebook in Google Colab with my hardware, but when I run the code my program is using only my CPU and not my GPU.
How I can fix that?
I'm using Keras and I'm trying to fine-tune the Inception V3.

Comment: What do you mean connect colab with your hardware? Colab runs on a remote server, not on your local hardware

Comment: Colab has a feature to connect to a local Jupyter server.

Comment: Do you have TensorFlow GPU installed?